# Swagger UI not working Rest APi

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a Rest Api project and I am trying to use swagger to documentation and UI. I was able to get the documentation but UI is not seeing api documentation and pulls up blank. I have copied contents of dist folder under webapps/WEB-INF
I can access the documentation using: http://localhost:8080/ml-api-ws/v2/api-docs I tried to change the url in index.html to point to this documentation but was swagger pulls up blank.

webapps/WEB-INF:

[image]

Blank Swagger:

[image]
index.html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
      if (url && url.length > 1) {
        url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
      } else {
        //url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json";
        url = "http://localhost:8080/ml-api-ws/v2/api-docs";
      }
```

Pom.xml

```
<!-- SpringFox Dependency For Swagger -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Swagger UI Depedency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epsilon.al.ml.controller" />

<mvc:resources  mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources  mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/webjars/"/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>       
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="swagger2Config" class = "springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration" />
    <!-- <bean name="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" 
        /> <bean name="jsonTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" 
        /> -->
</beans>
```

Web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>MlApi</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>      
        <param-value>classpath:*-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 

  <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ml-rest-api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ml-rest-api</servlet-name>
        <!-- <url-pattern>/ml-api-ws/*</url-pattern> -->
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!--    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> -->
        <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I also tried saving the the api documentation in .json file and explore with swagger-ui but the page did not do anything.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this but creating a folder under webapps and moving contents of dist folder inside this. Once I had this I then added mapping for index.html in servlet.xml and was able to access the api's.

Comment: Were you able to save the the api documentation in .json ?

Comment: I was able to access the json using the URL which fit my needs.